# Automatic PyQt GUI generation according to REST schema

Tags: django, rest, pyqt, pyqt5

**TL;DR:** I'd like to have a tool that receives an RESTful schema as input and provides a pyqt dialog/UI as output. Preferably with automatic submission/validation.

I'm working on a PyQt5 application that interacts with a remote Django server using django-rest-framework.

I find that I define most of my models/views/serializers quite quickly as they neatly extend one another. After writing a proper model, generating serializer and view is very easy and I end up with fully functioning server-side fast.

The client/GUI side is a different matter. I have to define the available fields again, their type and order. I have to define widgets for viewing a single object and a list of objects. I have to define edit interfaces and handle permissions.

This all seems like it could use some sort of automation.
Ideally, I could point a smart widget or form to a REST endpoint, and it'll automatically fetch the schema and allowed actions. Automatically create a GUI and the necessary error handling.
Ideally, this shouldn't depend on server side technology, and simply use a schema.

I've googled and couldn't find anything like that. Can someone point me at something similar? Is there a deeper issue with creating such a tool I'm missing?

Thanks!